# How can I correctly implement an Hibernate SQL query starting from an SQL query that count the number of rows?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-session

I am absolutly new in Hibernate and I have the following problem.

I have this standard SQL query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TID003_ANAGEDIFICIO anagraficaEdificio 
INNER JOIN TID002_CANDIDATURA candidatura 
  ON (candidatura.PRG_PAR = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_PAR AND candidatura.PRG_CAN = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_CAN)
INNER JOIN TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA anagPartecipa ON(anagPartecipa.PRG_PAR = candidatura.PRG_PAR)
INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst ON (provNuovIst.COD_PRV_NIS = anagPartecipa.COD_PRV_NIS)
WHERE anagraficaEdificio.FLG_GRA = 1 AND provNuovIst.COD_REG = "SI";
```

This works fine and return an **integer** number.

The important thing to know is that in this query the only 
parameter that can change (inserted by the user in the frontend of a webappplication) is the last one (this one: **provNuovIst.COD_REG = "SI"**).

So, the application on which I am working use Hibernate and the requirement say that I have to implement this query using **Hibernate Native SQL**, I have found this tutorial:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm

that show this example:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id = :employee_id";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Employee.class);
query.setParameter("employee_id", 10);
List results = query.list();
```

that, from what I have understand (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion), involves the use of an **Employee** model class. So th prvious query first define the query (using the **:param_name** syntax for the parameter), then create an **SQLQuery** Hibernate object, add the class used for the result, set the previous parameter neam and finally obtain a List (that I think Hibernate create as something like an **ArrayList**) with the retrieved object.

My problem is that I simply I have to obtain an **integer** value (because I have a **SELECT count(*)**, so I will obtain an integer value and not a set of rows).

So how can I correctly use the **Hibernate Native SQL** to implement my SQL query into my Hibernate repository class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SQLQuery.uniqueResult` to retrieve a single value from the query:

```
String sql = "SELECT count(*) ...";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
// set parameters...
int count = ((Number)query.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```